# Python: Issue converting ISO 8601 to datetime object

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, datetime

I'm struggling to convert ISO 8601 datetime coming from angular datetime component on the client side in the python backend. The date is coming from the *angular-material-datetimepicker* library in this format: `'2016-10-24T10:00:00.000Z'`. How do I convert to a datetime object to send to the datastore? I'm using Google App Engine. Here's what I've tried fiddling with in pycharm among other things I've found on other forums;

**works**

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-24T10:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 24, 10, 0)
```

**does not work**

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-24T10:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

[image]

As seen above, the first command with the 'nanoseconds i think?' does not work. That is the actual format angular sends through. When I remove `.000` it works as seen in the second command. What method call should I execute on the first date for it to work? Also I tried;

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-24T10:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ')
```

Comment: Please insert your output and code as `code` so that people can search for it and use it, instead of pasting a screenshot.

Comment: Why is that strange? You're missing the format for the microseconds